# Hadoop MapReduce Yarn example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, ubuntu-14.04, hadoop-yarn

I am following [this tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html).
I run hadoop on virtual machine with ubuntu 14.04 32bit installed. I tried many configurations and solutions for similar problems but it didn't work.
When I execute jar, I will get this error:

```
hduser@branislav-vm:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
15/12/15 23:40:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/12/15 23:40:08 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/12/15 23:40:10 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1450251211211_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1550)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3110)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3034)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:723)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1430)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
15/12/15 23:40:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1450251211211_0001
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1450251211211_0001/job.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1550)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3110)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3034)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:723)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1430)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
```

JPS:

```
hduser@branislav-vm:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps
15120 NameNode
16481 Jps
15458 SecondaryNameNode
15926 NodeManager
15799 ResourceManager
```

EDIT1:
I removed tmp and logs folder and lets do that again.

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode/
$ rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode/
$ rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop/output
$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/hadoop-hduser/dfs
$ rm -rf /usr/local/hadoop/logs

$ start-dfs.sh 
15/12/16 02:38:59 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-branislav-vm.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-branislav-vm.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-branislav-vm.out
15/12/16 02:39:22 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

$ jps
15923 DataNode
16206 Jps
16095 SecondaryNameNode
```

Now NameNode did not start. This is hadoop-hduser-namenode-branislav-vm.out

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /usr/local/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

and .log file from first WARN:

```
2015-12-16 02:39:04,417 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode does not exist
2015-12-16 02:39:04,422 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Encountered exception loading fsimage
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:327)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:215)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:975)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:584)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:644)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:811)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:795)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1488)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
2015-12-16 02:39:04,438 INFO org.mortbay.log: Stopped HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:50070
2015-12-16 02:39:04,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping NameNode metrics system...
2015-12-16 02:39:04,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system stopped.
2015-12-16 02:39:04,439 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2015-12-16 02:39:04,439 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:327)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:215)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:975)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:681)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:584)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:644)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:811)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:795)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1488)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1554)
2015-12-16 02:39:04,441 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
2015-12-16 02:39:04,446 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at branislav-vm/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

YARN successfully starts.

Comment: Can you check log for datanode and see why it failed to start? your errorlog and jps suggests that datanode is down....pls chk

Comment: Can you stop all the components, format the namenode again and start the dfs again? we can take up to chat and try trouble shooting your problem

Comment: This error: "There are 0 datanode(s) running" clearly indicates that Zero Data Nodes are running. I had answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34245682/could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-minreplication-1-there-are-4/34250778#34250778. Can you check, if there is a problem with your Data Node?